# How to start video during audio call in sinch

Tags: sinch, videochat, video-conferencing, android-sinch-api

Using Sinch SDK

1) i have made a video call. i have a button in my GUI. i want to turn off video by clicking the button to make the call like a audio call.

i am starting video call as

```
Call call = getSinchServiceInterface().callUserVideo("user1");
String callId = call.getCallId();
Intent callScreen = new Intent(this, RunningVideoCallActivity.class);
callScreen.putExtra(SinchService.CALL_ID, callId);
startActivity(callScreen);
```

2) i have made an audio call. i have a button in my GUI. i want to start video by clicking the button to make the call like a video call.

i am starting audio call as

```
Call call = getSinchServiceInterface().callUser("user1");
String callId = call.getCallId();
Intent callScreen = new Intent(this, RunningAudioCallActivity.class);
callScreen.putExtra(SinchService.CALL_ID, callId);
startActivity(callScreen);
```

3) How to mute a call in Sinch.

4) how to hold a call in Sinch. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You cant start video in the audio call, what you could do is to always start an audio call and pause the video in the beginning to make it look like an audio call. WE dont have hold functionality.

To mute use mute and unmute on the audio controller

Comment: i want to turn off video during a video call. how can i do that.

Comment: and also want to turn ON video during an audio call

Answer (score 0):

Hope this comes useful for Future readers.

You really can't switch between `callUserVideo` and `callUser` while on an ongoing call.
But there is an alternate way to achieve the functionality. This is what Sinch Support team says,

> you can pause video and do voice only, so all calls are video and you can pause / resume the video track

So what this means is, you have to start the call always with `callUserVideo`, in case you want to toggle between audio and video. 
So for toggling between Audio and Video, you need to do some thing like this. In the page where you are handling the incoming call client.

```
// function to be called when you want to toggle to video call
private void resumeVideo() {
    if (mVideoCall != null) {
        mVideoCall.resumeVideo();
    }
}

// enable speaker
// add remote and local video views
private void resumeVideoCallback() {
    mAudioCallToggle.setText("Switch to AudioCall");
    if (getSinchServiceInterface() != null && getSinchServiceInterface().getAudioController() != null) {
        getSinchServiceInterface().getAudioController().enableSpeaker();
    }
    addLocalView();
    addRemoteView();
}

// function to be called when you want to toggle to audio call
private void pauseVideo() {
    if (mVideoCall != null) {
        mVideoCall.pauseVideo();
    }
}

// disable speaker
// remove remote and local video views
private void pauseVideoCallback() {
    mAudioCallToggle.setText("Switch to VideoCall");
    if (getSinchServiceInterface() != null && getSinchServiceInterface().getAudioController() != null) {
        getSinchServiceInterface().getAudioController().disableSpeaker();
    }
    removeVideoViews();
}
```

And on your video call listener, implement like this

```
    .............
    .............
    other implementations
    .............
    .............
    @Override
    public void onVideoTrackAdded(Call call) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Video track added");
        addRemoteView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoTrackPaused(Call call) {
        pauseVideoCallback();
    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoTrackResumed(Call call) {
        resumeVideoCallback();
    }
```

And finally to toggle between Audio/Video, do something like this

```
new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mAudioCallToggle.getTag().equals("Audio")) {
            mAudioCallToggle.setTag("Video");
            pauseVideo();
        } else {
            mAudioCallToggle.setTag("Audio");
            resumeVideo();
        }
    }
}
```